# What's the difference between 変態 and 痴女 (or 痴漢)?

Tags: meaning, words, nuances, manga, word-usage

In the [Dead Tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Tube) manga, a girl is being accused of being a 痴女【ちじょ】, at which she replies:

> 私変態だけど痴女じゃないもん！！

What's the difference between the two words? Is 変態 just a pervert and 痴女 someone that actually sexually assaults people?

Comment: Which manga was this?

Comment: @ラメージルーカス I updated the question with the name of the manga and link to the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

変態 are people with abnormal sexual preferences. They can be men or women. 痴女(women) or 痴漢(men) are people who have committed sexual crimes. So, she can be 変態 and not a 痴女 if she has abnormal sexual preferences but does not act on them. [Japanese wiki explains this.](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%89%E6%85%8B%E6%80%A7%E6%AC%B2)

To me, when I use 痴女(women) or 痴漢(men), I am not saying if their sexual preferences are abnormal or not but I am saying that they are doing something sexual in abnormal manners, meaning criminal manners.

Comment: But “痴女” used in Japanese pornography doesn’t really have anything to do with criminality... it’s probably closer to “nympho” in English (i.e., sex-obsessed).