# What is the difference between 売女 vs 街娼?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, kanji, kanji-choice

After reading, [What's the difference between 変態 and 痴女 (or 痴漢)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/46969/34281), I did a few word searches.

Jisho lists multiple words when searching for the term [Whore](https://jisho.org/search/Whore):

- [売女](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%A3%B2%E5%A5%B3) - prostitute; whore​
- [街娼](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A1%97%E5%A8%BC) - prostitute; whore; streetwalker​

Can someone explain the difference?

See also:

- [Multiple common kanji for a word: which to use?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23607/34281)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both 売女{ばいた} and 街娼{がいしょう} are derogatory terms. So, they aren't used at all. The following are more often heard:

[風俗嬢{ふうぞくじょう}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%A2%A8%E4%BF%97%E5%AC%A2) is used as "prostitute".

[立{た}ちんぼ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A1%E3%82%93%E3%81%BC_(%E6%9B%96%E6%98%A7%E3%81%95%E5%9B%9E%E9%81%BF)) is used as "streetwalker"​.

These words do not connote ["*puta madre*"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=puta%20madre) in Spanish. So you can't use them as a compliment.

Comment: Interesting note regarding the Spanish terminology. I am quite aware that they are both derogatory, but why would they not be used at all? For example, what would be used in a character description for a story highlighting this on TV for the news?

Comment: @ラメージルーカス I do not know the true reason for not being used often tho. However, I assume 売女{ばいた} was not officially permitted different from other [遊女](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%81%8A%E5%A5%B3#cite_note-8) . Wikipedia explains 「遊郭以外で売春するものを隠売女と称し、厳しく取り締まった」The police strictly controlled prostitutes working other than brothel called 遊郭{ゆうかく} where government officially permits prostitution and named them 隠売女{いんばいた}. They should have been ranked lower among prostitutes for the reason. That's why the term has still not been paid attention to. For 街娼, it could be the similar reason.